# Changing matshow xticklabel position from top to bottom of the figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm using matshow() in matplotlib and the figures generated has the xticklabels on top by default. Is there a way to put the xticklabels on the bottom instead?

Appreciate any help with this.
/M

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try doing the following to adjust the x ticks positions:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
```

Similarly, for the y ticks:

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
```

Comment: Wonderful! 

Thanks a lot :-)

/M

Comment: If it doesn't work, be sure that you run this command after calling matshow()!